# element onkeydown keycode javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am using this code snippet to add KeyDown event handler to any element in the html form

```
for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
{
    ele[i].onkeydown = function()
    {
            alert('onkeydown');
    } 
}
```

How can I know which key has been pressed on keydown event? I try this

```
for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
{
    ele[i].onkeydown = function(e)
    {
           alert(e.KeyCode);
    } 
}
```

but it is not working, why?
Thanks a lot

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to detect printable characters or other keys? For the former you should handle the `keypress` event, for the latter it's `keydown`.

Comment: I want to change 'enter' press to 'tab'

Comment: KeyCode should be keyCode
 document.onkeydown = function(e){alert(String(e.keyCode));} 
Worked for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the code I use for this problem. It works in every browser.

```
//handle "keypress" for all "real characters"     
if (event.type == "keydown") {
    //some browsers support evt.charCode, some only evt.keyCode
   if (event.charCode) {
      var charCode = event.charCode;
   }
   else {
      var charCode = event.keyCode;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great, can I change this code to tab? event.charCode = 9 or event.keyCode = 9  is not working :(

Comment: You can try it by printing the char code when pressing keys in different browsers to see the exact code to use. In my experience some keys have different codes in IE and Mozilla

Comment: Really? Is that working in non-IE browsers? Where does `event` come from?

Comment: I tested it only on IE, do you have suggestion for non IE browsers @Tim?

Answer (score 3):

For detecting Enter, you could use the following code, which will work in all mainstream browsers. It uses the `keypress` event rather than `keydown` because Enter produces a printable character:

```
ele[i].onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    if (charCode == 13) {
        alert("Enter");
        // Do stuff here
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I used this:

```
function check(){
 if (event.keyCode == 32){
  alert("Space is pressed");
 }
}
```

and in my body tag: `onKeyPress="check()"`

Answer (score 0):

It is `keyCode`, not `KeyCode`.