# how to open link or button by pressing F2 in html?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.in">Google.com</a>
```

I want this to open when I press F2 or any function key...

Comment: possible duplicate of [element onkeydown keycode javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629926/element-onkeydown-keycode-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the onkeydown method.

```
 document.onkeydown = function(){
 if(window.event && window.event.keyCode == 113) 
 {
    window.location.href = "http://www.yoursite.com"
 }
}
```

Here you could use anything instead of 113.F2 is 113 is ascii.F1 is 112,F3 is 114 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.onkeydown = function(){
if(window.event && window.event.keyCode == 113) 
{
   window.location.href = "http://www.google.com"
}
}
```

Comment: And I think that the proper syntax for that redirect is: `window.location.href = 'https://www.google.co.in';`.

Comment: Is it correct
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<script>
document.onkeydown = function(){
if(window.event && window.event.keyCode == 113) 
{
window.location("https://www.google.co.in");
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <a href="https://www.google.co.in">Google.com</a>
</body>
</html>` because its not working

Comment: @HashirHussain see the answer now..I have updated it..

Answer (score 0):

**Here you have an implementation of your requirements using jquery: jsfiddle.net/96rLf/2.**

The main part is this: [jsfiddle.net/96rLf/2.](http://jsfiddle.net/96rLf/2)
You can use jquery

```
<input type="button" accesskey="?" value="Next Item">

$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37: case 38:  //key is left or up
            if (currImage <= 1) {break;} //if is the first one do nothing
            goToPrev(); // function which goes to previous image
            return false; //"return false" will avoid further events
        case 39: case 40: //key is left or down
            if (currImage >= maxImages) {break;} //if is the last one do nothing
            goToNext(); // function which goes to next image
            return false; //"return false" will avoid further events
    }
    return; //using "return" other attached events will execute
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <script> 
        document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown, false);

        function keyDown(e) 
        {
            var keyCode = e.keyCode;
            if(keyCode==113) {window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";}
        }
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://www.google.co.in">Google.com</a> 
</body>
</html>
```